# Can't arrange displays correctly

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have three monitors setup and they are working correctly with one exception:

Windows won't let me arrange my displays correctly. My third monitor is on top of the other two and whenever I try to arrange them, it reverts to being side by side.

**What I'm attempting to do**

[image]

**What I get after hitting apply**

[image]

After I hit apply, the third monitor falls down so they are all in one row.

I'm using an AMD Radeon R7 240 (latest drivers). Display 1 is connected to the card via HDMI, display 2 is connected to the card via VGA and display 3 is connected via a *HDMI/USB adapter*. I suspect that the adapter is contributing to the problem.

This is the adapter I am using:
https://www.startech.com/AV/USB-Video-Adapters/slim-usb-3-hdmi-adapter~USB32HDES#dnlds

I have tried connecting the other displays with the adapter instead, but the issue persists.

How can I get Windows to allow me to arrange my third monitor on top of the others?

**Update**
I just discovered that if I set #3 to portrait instead of landscape it works (unfortunately I want it in landscape mode). It also works if I lower the resolution of display 3, however I would like to make this work using the native resolution of the display.

Comment: I assume all display are working? Is it perhaps possible to arrange screens in the AMD graphics driver? I don't have AMD graphics, so I can't check.

Comment: @DanielB Yes all displays are working correctly. I have tried doing this through the AMD UI as well as through windows, no luck.

Comment: i have 3 monitors and I was able to arrange it the way you wanted.  so it is definitely possible.

Comment: Do you have on-board graphics you can attach the third monitor to?

Comment: Try [Actual Multiple Monitors](http://www.actualtools.com/multiplemonitors/order/) (24.95$ with trial).

Comment: @harrymc did you ever get this working? I've just got a 4th monitor that is on a. Second row, but it won't let me arrange it properly (same issue as you)

Comment: @andrew: I'm not the original poster.

Comment: @harrymc haha sorry :) I managed to "fix" it like the OP as well (by shrinking the resolution down on the top screen). Not ideal, but at least it lets me show the screens how I want now

Answer (score 2):

AMD, Control Catalyst Center

1. Download the correct/updated drivers.
2. Download the Control Catalys Center software for your Windows and Radeon.

Link:

AMD Radeon Drivers and Software: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download
Also on this link, right side of the page, under "Latest AMD Drivers and Software" download the correct software for your Windows system.

Guid to use the Catalyst Control Center for Multiple Monitors:
http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/737-27130CannotenableTV-OutinCatalystControlCenter.aspx

Regarding your update: Have you tried setting up the DPI manually? A correct Resolution can also help.

[image]

**Note**: What then you'd want to do is **set each screen independently** with "screen sizing", utilizing the **buttons on the actual monitor**.

Comment: I already have the latest drivers. It doesn't matter if I try arranging the displays through the Windows settings or through CCC, I get the same result. I'm not sure what you mean by "setting up the DPI manually". Can you clarify?

Comment: @mtinsley On the screen settings you can adjust height width.. you can also set the resolution, 720x 1280x 480x etc.

Comment: @mtinsley Added screenshot to illustrate resolution.

Comment: When I change the resolution, I can arrange display 3 on top of the others (just like when I change the orientation). However, this just introduced a different problem: Now it isn't using the native resolution of the monitor. I would like to make it work without having to use a lower resolution.

Comment: The menu Robin mentioned doesn't seem to exist (for me at least). I'm using the latest version of Windows 10 (anniversary update).

Comment: Set each monitor's resolution. Since you have AMD Radeon,  you should try the software for the device as an option. Are you using Extend? If you are using extend you are Extending the same resolution and setting to the Extended Monitor. You can't mix if you are extending. If you are using the same exact monitor then Extend will be exactly the same. Think of Extend as "wrapping" the view.

Comment: @mtinsley Read above comment. I added one last note on my answer above; using each monitor's screen-sizing buttons. Get your main monitor on the setting you want, then set the extended monitors manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing this in Control Panel instead (`Appearance and Personalisation > Display > Screen Resolution`). Setting it in the Windows 10 settings application failed for me too.

Video: http://files.robinmc.com/resolution.mp4

Comment: There is no "Screen Resolution" option under display in WIndows 10. There is a "Change display settings" option, but that displays the same setting interface that I've been using.

Comment: There is for me, http://i.imgur.com/ULkmt1A.png. The option on the left is named differently ("Adjust resolution"). With the path in my answer I meant as it appears in windows explorer at the top of the window

Comment: Welcome to [su]! This answer is better as a comment, but is at least helpful. I decided not to flag it for deletion, but it barely passes muster as an answer.

Comment: It is not there for me, using the latest version of Windows 10 (anniversary update).

Comment: I added a video to my answer, that might help you. I am not using the anniversary update by the way, but I don't believe Microsoft would remove such an option from the control panel.